# Highcharts don't correctly update with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to dynamically update my Highcharts chart based on an observable configuration in an Angular component. I'm using an observable with ngIf like this:

```html
<highcharts-chart
  *ngIf="conf | async as options"
  [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
  [options]="options"
>
</highcharts-chart>
```

However, when my conf observable swith options between a column chart and a stacked column chart, the stacked values don't appear. Similarly, when I switch from a stacked column chart to a pie chart, unexpected slices appear.

To help you visualize the problem, I've created these StackBlitz demos with the configuration of a chart that is updated after 5 seconds:

- Column to stacked column: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular14-standaone-components-highcharts-8dpdrx?file=src/app/app.component.ts
- Stacked column to pie: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular14-standaone-components-highcharts-agjsit?file=src/app/app.component.ts

In both demos, the initial configuration works correctly, as you can see in these JSFiddles:

- Pie chart: https://jsfiddle.net/jzs7ubkh/11/
- Stacked column chart: https://jsfiddle.net/6Lf5hsm4/
- Column chart: https://jsfiddle.net/jzs7ubkh/12/

Can anyone help me understand why my dynamic updates aren't working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular wrapper uses `chart.update` to apply changes to a chart, which means that the chart is not recreated, so the previous options are also used. This causes you to have more series than you expect.

Issue reproduced in pure JS: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ngLroxsu/

Enabling `oneToOne` option resolves the problem, but please also check the docs and keep in mind how the changes in options are applied.

```
<highcharts-chart
  ...
  [oneToOne]=true
>
</highcharts-chart>
```

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular14-standaone-components-highcharts-rydlns

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#options-details

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update